# How to enter memo strings between two lines without delete the content of the next line?

Tags: c++, c++builder, firemonkey, firemonkey-fm3, c++builder-xe6

I just would like some help when adding contents between two lines...
If I have this on Memo:

```
//--------------------------------------------------
//---------- Mauro Mascarenhas de Araújo -----------
//--------------------------------------------------
```

I would like add a line before the last line (on this case, because I need this function to do it in a bigger way than on this example), something like that:

```
//--------------------------------------------------
//---------- Mauro Mascarenhas de Araújo -----------
//------------ C++ Programer aprentice -------------
//--------------------------------------------------
```

I've tried to find some integrated function that could do that, but I haven't found. If you can help me with that, I would be very happy.

Are there any ready function or should I create two TStrings components, copy the memo content since the begining, untill the line '1' (on this case - so, the line I wanted), and use the other to copy the since the line '3' (on this case - so, the line after I wanted untill the end) Rewrite the memo with the first component add the lines I want, and after add the lines of the second component. - I know it is confusing, that's  why I'm tryng to find a ready function.

Since now, THANKS A LOT.

Comment: For future reference, you can post answers to your own questions.  You don't need to edit the question to state the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found a how to:

```
Form1->Memo1->Lines->Insert(int line, String StringIWant);
```

Thanks for everybody who at least though in answering me XD.